# Is there a way to get total pinned memory size in linux?

Tags: memory, memory-management, pytorch, torch, pinned-memory

It seems there is a way to get a **single process**'s pinned memory size by checking: `cat /proc/<PID>/status | grep Vm` on linux command line. And the result may be like follows:

[image]

But I have two questions here:

1. How can I get total pinned memory size in the whole system?
2. The single process's `VmPin` and `VmLck` seems to be still all zeros after I use `torch.tensor(xxx, pin_memory=True)` to allocate some host-pinned memory. What's wrong here?